# safesquid external parser

Tags: linux, python, squid

i am running safesquid and it does support an external parser, so i wrote this simple URL rewrite code in python which also logs the initial request...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys
def modify_url(line):
    list = line.split(' ')
    old_url = list[0]
    new_url = '\n'
    if old_url.endswith('.avi'):
        new_url = 'http://www.yahoo.com'
    else:
        new_url = old_url
    return new_url

def main():
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
        log = open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a')
        log.write(line + "\n")
        log.close()
        new_url = modify_url(line)
        sys.stdout.write(new_url)
        sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get these errors on safesquid

```
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] request: request for web interface from 192.168.221.1
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] external: parsed with /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/redirect.py
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] external: error: external parser sent null or invalid request headers
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] error: security: malformatted header received
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] external: parsed with /opt/safesquid/safesquid/scripts/redirect.py
2012 01 30 17:19:45 [225] external: error: external parser sent null or invalid request headers
```

Also the initial request log is EMPTY however the file is large, i guess it must be appending "\n" to the file....

Any ideas how i can capture the requests from safesquid?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite or redirect a URL, then you can simply use the [URL Redirect](http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=29) or [Re-Write Document](http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=35) feature of SafeSquid.

Comment: thats ok, but i need to run an external program which does some checks on my internal database...